# Reactjs useEffect not showing all datas on page (after using useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usecallback

At first i was fixing the error "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:" by adding the useCallback.
Then new issue comes up, the API should return 10 items but only first items show on page.
Wondering which part is getting wrong and cause the data not render correctly?

Here is the code:

```
const InStream = () => {
  const [gallery, setGallery] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  let [color] = useState("#1E9A4B"); 

  const getAPI = useCallback(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        let keys = res.values[0];
        let newData = res.values.slice(1, res.values.length);

        let formatted = [],
          data = newData,
          cols = keys,
          l = cols.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var d = data[i],
            o = {};
          for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) o[cols[j]] = d[j];
          formatted.push(o);
          setGallery(formatted);
          setLoading(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        setTimeout(() => {
          getAPI();
        }, 1000);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAPI();
  }, [getAPI]);
return (// my code rendering gallery data // )
export default InStream;
```

Comment: Here a screenshot for reference https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/32438167?key=d4d5f5fc62d7d9c434aa33be1bceff8e
thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `setGallery` and `setLoading` out of loop

Comment: OMG my eye! can't spot this at all, thank you so much!